# Error after upgrading netbeans to 7.2

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform, logfiles

I was using netbeans 6.1 then I upgrade it to netbeans 7.2
when I tried to run my previous java source code errors showed out

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jrelog4j_jgap_lf.log (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:136)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:290)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:194)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:164)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:257)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:133)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:97)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:689)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:647)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:544)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:440)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:476)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:471)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:125)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:289)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1116)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:914)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:604)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:310)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
    at net.didion.jwnl.util.MessageLog.<init>(MessageLog.java:11)
    at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.Dictionary.<clinit>(Dictionary.java:24)
```

any idea how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not allowed to write to the given folder, or the spaces in the path name are the reason for the problem.

Can you try to configure the path fro the log file into a different directory, preferable without a space in it's name?